# swing drawing and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to create a simple waveform visualizer, my problem is coordinating threads using swing to draw lines. I've divided part of the code between an external thread that does the math and the swing thread to draw the line. For some reason I can't get the code to work, but if I call getGraphics() somehow some lines can be seen even if it flicks a lot.

```
package it.pievis.GUI;
import it.pievis.utils.BackgroundExecutor;
import it.pievis.utils.Utils;

public class WaveformFrame extends JFrame {

    private int WIDTH = 450;
    private int HEIGHT = 100;
    private JLabel testLbl = new JLabel();
    private WaveformPanel wfp;

    public WaveformFrame() {
        super();
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT+20);
        setTitle("Waveform Frame");
        setName("Main FRAME");
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        wfp = new WaveformPanel();
        wfp.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        wfp.setName("Waveform PANEL");
        add(wfp);
    }

    public void updateWave(byte[] pcmdata)
    {
        wfp.updateWave(pcmdata);
    }

    class WaveformPanel extends JPanel
    {
        byte[] pcmdata = null;

        /**
         * Refresh the wave every times a new pcmdata arrives
         */
        public void updateWave(byte[] pcmdata)
        {
            log("pcmdata received");
            this.pcmdata = pcmdata;
        }

        /**
         * Handle the refresh of the waveform
         * @param g
         */
        private void doDrawing(Graphics g){

            //log("ThreadSwing: " + Thread.currentThread());

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            log( g2d.hashCode() + " drawing");
            int HEIGHT = getHeight();
            int WIDTH = getWidth();

            if(pcmdata == null){
                //Render a straight line
                g2d.drawLine(0, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT/2);
                return;
            }
            //Let swing handle the drawing
            BackgroundExecutor.get().execute(new WaveformTask(g2d, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        }

        class WaveformTask implements Runnable
        {
            Graphics2D g2d;
            int HEIGHT;
            int WIDTH;
            int val0;
            int val1;
            int diffx0;
            int diffx1;

            public WaveformTask(Graphics2D g2d, int width, int height) {
                this.g2d = g2d;
                HEIGHT = height;
                WIDTH = width;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                float scale = (float) HEIGHT/65536;
                int nlines = pcmdata.length/4;
                float lineLen = (float) WIDTH/(nlines-1);
                ArrayList<Line2D.Float> lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Float>();
                for(int i = 0; i < nlines-4; i+=4){
                    int sample0 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+1], pcmdata[i]);
                    int sample1 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+3], pcmdata[i+2]);
                    int val0 = (int) (sample0*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
                    int val1 = (int) (sample1*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
                    int diffx0 = Math.round(lineLen*i);
                    int diffx1 = Math.round(lineLen*i+1);
                    lines.add(new Line2D.Float(diffx0, val0, diffx1, val1));
                    //log("Updated GUI ( " + sumData + ") " + lineLen +  " " + WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT + " nlines: " +nlines + " Scale: "+scale );
                    //Let swing handle the drawing

                }
                //log("Thread0: " + Thread.currentThread());
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new drawLinesTask(g2d,lines));
            }
        }

        /**
         * This task draws lines on screen
         */
        class drawLinesTask implements Runnable
        {
            ArrayList<Line2D.Float> lines;
            Graphics2D g2d;

            public drawLinesTask(Graphics2D g2d, ArrayList<Line2D.Float> lines) {
                this.g2d = g2d;
                this.lines = lines;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //IF I UNCOMMENT THIS IT SORTA WORKS
                //g2d = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
                log( g2d.hashCode() + " run " + getName());
                for(Line2D.Float line : lines)
                {
                    g2d.draw(line);
                }
                //log("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
                log("lines have been drawn");
                getContentPane().repaint();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Called each time the UI is rendered
         */
        /**
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            doDrawing(g);
        }*/

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            doDrawing(g);
        }
    }
    /// END OF JPANEL CLASS
}
```

I've no idea why it's not working, I've made some test, I see that the graphics component is the same and that I'm in fact working on the Jpanel and in the swing thread. I don't understand why by doing this nothing can be seen, but if I use getGraphics and then I repring, something shows up and flicks.
Sorry for the long block of code, I hope someone can help me understand what's going on.

Comment: Everything that you want to paint has to be painted in the `paintComponent` method (or in methods that are called from there), using the given `Graphics` object. You may **NOT** store the `Graphics` object to use it later. One can say that this `Graphics` object is only "valid" until the `paintComponent` method finished. You may also **NOT** call `getGraphics`, because you never know whether you receive a "valid" `Graphics` object.

Comment: You basically have to store everything that you want to paint (e.g. in a `List<Line2D>`, and paint these things from the `paintComponent` method. Your code involves too many third-party classes to show exactly what you have to change, but maybe you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed my problem. I thought it was possible to draw outside of it, being careful about being in the swing thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is my working code, thanks to the commenter I was able to get this working:

package it.pievis.GUI;

public class WaveformFrame extends JFrame {

```
private int WIDTH = 450;
private int HEIGHT = 100;
private WaveformPanel wfp;
private ArrayList<Line2D.Float> lines;

public WaveformFrame() {
    super();
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT+20);
    setTitle("Waveform Frame");
    setName("Main FRAME");
    wfp = new WaveformPanel();
    wfp.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    wfp.setName("Waveform PANEL");
    add(wfp);
}

public void updateWave(byte[] pcmdata)
{
    wfp.updateWave(pcmdata);
    //wfp.doDrawing(getGraphics());
    //repaint();
}

class WaveformPanel extends JPanel
{
    byte[] pcmdata = null;

    /**
     * Refresh the wave every times a new pcmdata arrives
     */
    public void updateWave(byte[] pcmdata)
    {
        //log("pcmdata received");
        this.pcmdata = pcmdata;
        doDrawing(getGraphics());
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Handle the refresh of the waveform
     * @param g
     */
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g){

        //log("ThreadSwing: " + Thread.currentThread());

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int HEIGHT = getHeight();
        int WIDTH = getWidth();

        if(pcmdata == null){
            //Render a straight line
            g2d.drawLine(0, HEIGHT/2, WIDTH, HEIGHT/2);
            //g2d.drawLine(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            return;
        }
        /*
        float scale = (float) HEIGHT/65536;
        int nlines = pcmdata.length/2;
        float lineLen = (float) WIDTH/(nlines-1);
        if(lineLen < 1)
            lineLen = 1;
        int sumData = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < nlines-2; i+=2){
            int sample0 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+1], pcmdata[i]);
            int sample1 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+3], pcmdata[i+2]);
            int val0 = (int) (sample0*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
            int val1 = (int) (sample1*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
            int diffx0 = Math.round(lineLen*i);
            int diffx1 = Math.round(lineLen*i+2);
            g2d.drawLine(diffx0, val0, diffx1, val1);
            log("- x0 " + diffx0 + " y " + val0);
            sumData = val0 + val1;
            //log("Updated GUI ( " + sumData + ") " + lineLen +  " " + WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT + " nlines: " +nlines + " Scale: "+scale );
        }
        */
        //Let swing handle the drawing
        BackgroundExecutor.get().execute(new WaveformTask(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        //Let swing handle the drawing
        if(lines != null){
            //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new drawLinesTask(g2d));
            //(new drawLinesTask(g2d)).run();
            drawLines(g2d);
            //repaint();
            }
    }

    class WaveformTask implements Runnable
    {
        Graphics2D g2d;
        int HEIGHT;
        int WIDTH;

        public WaveformTask(int width, int height) {
            HEIGHT = height;
            WIDTH = width;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            calcLine2d();
            //log("Thread0: " + Thread.currentThread());
        }

        void calcLine2d(){
            float scale = (float) HEIGHT/65536;
            int nlines = pcmdata.length/4;
            float lineLen = (float) WIDTH/(nlines-1);
            //Don't wanna work on the original thread
            ArrayList<Line2D.Float> lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Float>();
            for(int i = 0; i < nlines-4; i+=4){
                int sample0 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+1], pcmdata[i]);
                int sample1 = Utils.getSixteenBitSample(pcmdata[i+3], pcmdata[i+2]);
                int val0 = (int) (sample0*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
                int val1 = (int) (sample1*scale)+HEIGHT/2;
                int diffx0 = Math.round(lineLen*i);
                int diffx1 = Math.round(lineLen*i+1);
                lines.add(new Line2D.Float(diffx0, val0, diffx1, val1));
                //log("Updated GUI ( " + sumData + ") " + lineLen +  " " + WIDTH + " " + HEIGHT + " nlines: " +nlines + " Scale: "+scale );
            }
            synchronized (this) {
                WaveformFrame.this.lines = lines;
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * This should draw lines
     * @param g2d
     */
    synchronized void drawLines(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        for(Line2D.Float line : lines)
        {
            g2d.draw(line);
        }
        //log("lines have been drawn");
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Called each time the UI is rendered
     */
    /**
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }*/

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}

/// END OF JPANEL CLASS
private void log(String line)
{
    System.out.println("GUI out] " + line);
}
```

}